# How to display default check checkbox in Magento custom option in product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom-options

I have 4 check-boxes as custom options and I would like to display default check-box checked in Magento front end. There is no option in Magento admin site to achieve that.

Comment: please provide us with what you have tried so far to achieve this.

Comment: inshort display one checkbox check by default in magento product detail page

Comment: and that check box is a custom option from magneto admin panel custom option

Comment: That's not possible out-of-the-box, custom options don't work that way, easiest way would be to use some JS to check that box on page load.

Comment: yes @Prateek i done it using js and thank you so much for you kind information

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with jQuery. I hide the select element and add one checkbox with jQuery. According this code you have added also 4 checkbox, please try it. I hide the value of the select when user clicks the checkbox.
Now add code this location:

**app/design/frontend/your theme/default theme/template/catalog/product/view/view.phtml**

```
<div class="checkbox_div">
    <input class="checkbox product-view-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="product-view-checkbox<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"
        name="product_view_products[]" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
    <label for="product-view-checkbox<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"></label>enter preformatted text here
</div>
<p class="price_original" style="display:none;">Add here shown value code</p> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var element_id = '<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>';
        jQuery("#product-view-checkbox"+element_id).click(function(){
            jQuery(".price_original").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```